# How can I know the private members in an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>TargetProject</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:TargetProject.Target.TargetClass">
        </member>
        <member name="M:TargetProject.Target.TargetClass.#ctor">
        </member>
        <member name="M:TargetProject.Target.TargetClass.Function(System.String,System.Int32)">
            <summary>
            This is Public Member Function
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:TargetProject.Target.TargetClass.Function2(System.String,System.Int32)">
            <summary>
            This is Private Member Function
            </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

I built and extracted the xml file in the project, and I am trying to parse this xml in another project.

How to know the private members in an xml file?

Comment: This is the project xml file that is created when the project is built.

Comment: I just checked option in Project properties->configuration->Debug->Xml Documentation

Comment: Why do you want info on private members? They can't be accessed outside of the assembly (there is a way but not recommending it).

Comment: Only is there is a property in the xml file that indicates if it is public or private.

Comment: Because I want to make a Api Docs Builder without a private member

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have access to the assembly that goes with that XML file. Then you can reflect over the assembly, looking up types based on the member names. And `System.Type` can [tell you if it's public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.ispublic?view=net-6.0), as can [MethodInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.ispublic?view=net-6.0) and etc.

Comment: Is there any way to access the assembly from another project?